# Keras - preprocessing and scaling for forked architecture

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have data set that has two inputs `x1,x2` and output that has 1 binary value (0,1) and 45 real numbers (output vector has 46 attibutes in summary). I would like to use different loss functions for this 1 binary value and 45 real numbers, namely binary crossentropy and mean squared error.
My knowledge of Keras is very limited, so I am not even sure if this is the architecture I want. Is this the right way of doing this?

first, preprocessing:

```
# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("inputs.csv", delim_whitespace=True,header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Y = dataset[:,3:]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=123)
y_train_L, y_train_R = y_train[:,0], y_train[:,1:]
y_train_L = y_train_L.reshape(-1,1)
scalarX, scalarY_L, scalarY_R = MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler()
scalarX.fit(x_train)
scalarY_L.fit(y_train_L)
scalarY_R.fit(y_train_R)

x_train = scalarX.transform(x_train)
y_train_L = scalarY_L.transform(y_train_L)
y_train_R = scalarY_R.transform(y_train_R)
```

where `y_train_L`  is `left` part are just binary values and `y_train_R` are real numbers. I had to split them because when defining architecture:

```
# define and fit the final model

inputs = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],))
first =Dense(46, activation='relu')(inputs)

#last
layer45 = Dense(45, activation='linear')(first)
layer1 = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(first)
out = [layer1,layer45]
#end last

model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=out)
model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy','mean_squared_error'], optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, [y_train_L,y_train_R], epochs=1000, verbose=1)


Xnew = scalarX.transform(x_test)
y_test_L, y_test_R = y_test[:,0], y_test[:,1:]
y_test_L = y_test_L.reshape(-1,1)
y_test_L=scalarY_L.transform(y_test_L)
y_test_R=scalarY_R.transform(y_test_R)
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
```

`loss=['binary_crossentropy','mean_squared_error']` expects two different arrays in `model.fit(x_train, [y_train_L,y_train_R])`

then i have to do all the 'funny' tricks to get predicted values and compare them next to each other because `ynew = model.predict(Xnew)` return `list` of two `lists`, one for binary values and one for real numbers.

```
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("SCALED VALUES")
for i in range(len(Xnew)):
    print("X=%s\n P=%s,%s\n A=%s,%s" % (Xnew[i], ynew[0][i], ynew[1][i], y_test_L[i], y_test_R[i]))

inversed_X_test = scalarX.inverse_transform(Xnew)
inversed_Y_test_L = scalarY_L.inverse_transform(y_test_L)
inversed_Y_test_R = scalarY_R.inverse_transform(y_test_R)
inversed_y_predicted_L = scalarY_L.inverse_transform(ynew[0])
inversed_y_predicted_R = scalarY_R.inverse_transform(ynew[1])
print("REAL VALUES")
for i in range(len(inversed_X_test)):
    print("X=%s\n P=%s,%s\n A=%s,%s" % (inversed_X_test[i], inversed_y_predicted_L[i],inversed_y_predicted_R[i], inversed_Y_test_L[i],inversed_Y_test_R[i]))
```

questions:

1. Can I achieve this in cleaner way?
2. How can I measure loss? I would like to create chart of loss values during trening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The way you define your model seems correct and there is no 'cleaner' way of doing it (I would argue that Keras' functional API is as clean as it gets)

2) To visualize training loss, store the history of training in a variable:

```
history = model.fit(...)
```

This `history` object will contain the train and validation losses for each epoch, you can use itto make plots.

3) In your classification output (`layer1`), you want to use a `sigmoid` activation instead of `tanh`. The sigmoid function returns values between 0 and 1, `tanh` returns values between -1 and 1. Your `binary_crossentropy` loss function expects the former.